# No turbo boost on GCP N1 servers using Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, google-cloud-platform, turbo-boost

I have created a GCP machine with 12 cores, using the "N1 Series". Using `lscpu`, the CPU appears to be an Intel Xeon E5 v3 (Haswell) @ 2.30GHz.

According to [the GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms#intel_cpu_processors), these cores should run at:

- 2.3 GHz base frequency
- 2.8 GHz all-core turbo frequency
- 3.8 GHz single-core max turbo frequency

However in practice all cores stay at 2.30 GHz no matter the load! I understand that the underlying machine and CPU may be shared with other users, but I would still expect to hit at least the all-core turbo frequency.

Checking with `cpuid` it looks like Turbo Boost is not enabled:

```
$ cpuid | grep -i turbo
Intel Turbo Boost Technology = false
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually explained in the GCP documentation:

> - Most VMs get the all-core turbo frequency, even if only the base
>   frequency is advertised to the guest environment.
> - A VM's guest
>   environment reflects the base clock frequency, regardless of what
>   frequency the VM is actually running at.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms#frequency_behavior